# I can't fit Logistic Regression into model. How to solve this?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I ran this code in Google Colab:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# Initialize logreg model
logreg = LogisticRegression()

# Fit the model with data
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict model
y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate model using confusion matrix
cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
print('Confusion Matrix:\n', cnf_matrix)
```

and it gave me this output

```
<ipython-input-73-2bdb42bd97ad> in <module>()
      6 
      7 # Fit the model with data
----> 8 logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
      9 
     10 # Predict model

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    170 
    171 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

How to solve this?

My X variable are numeric columns and y variable is label column. I've tried this code `LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)` but it returned error also.

Comment: Show us how does your y_train loock like

print(type(y_train))
print(y_train[0:10])

Comment: @Vlad <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
2606     False
57228    False
8382      True
60281     True
48432    False
2510     False
29712     True
68162     True
60530     True
46682     True
Name: is_churn, dtype: object

Comment: @Vlad is the problem in the values of y_train?

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to clean your dataset before feeding it to a model.  Quickly try dropping missing values and duplicates and see if the problem remains.

Comment: @GerardoZinno there is no missing values in dataset and I actually have cleaned it

Comment: I think that the problem is that your targets are deducted to be of type `object` and sklearn cannot work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn doesn't recognize `Boolean` type target variables. Convert them to numerical to train:

```
y_train = y_train.astype('int')
```

If you want your predictions to show boolean values (instead of integers), you could later convert them to `Boolean`:

```
y_pred = y_pred.astype('bool')
```

Note: if you do decide to convert your predictions, make sure you're not predicting probabilities, but classes (i.e. output is `0` and `1`, not a 2-dimensional matrix of intermediate values; if you do predict probabilities, first convert them to classes, then do boolean conversion).